# Find same key value in PHP array and save them into output array with updated values

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I would like to compare 2 arrays in PHP and match them together with (array_one) `sku`, (array_two) `id`. Then push the result with updated price from array_two into `output`-array.

This is how I would do something similar using JS. Not sure how to do it in PHP.

```
array_one.forEach(product => {
  let matchedProducts = array_two.find(old => {
    return product["sku"] === old["id"];
  });
  if (JSON.stringify(matchedProducts) !== JSON.stringify(product)) {
    console.log(matchedProducts)
  }
});
```

**Arrau_one:**

```
[
  {
    "post_id": 18,
    "sku": "SNTP-UVS8P",
    "price": "59"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 17,
    "sku": "TD-SKU30548",
    "price": "129"
  },
  {
    "post_id": 16,
    "sku": "USBCV",
    "price": ""
  }
]
```

**Arrau_two:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "DFTS-P20PR",
    "price": "49"
  },
  {
    "id": "SNTP-UVS8P",
    "price": "79"
  },
  {
    "id": "SNTP-UVS8P",
    "price": "49"
  },
  {
    "id": "USBCV",
    "price": "99"
  },
  {
    "id": "KS-12SEA2",
    "price": "29"
  }
]
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "post_id": 18,
    "sku": "SNTP-UVS8P",
    "price": "79" //Updated Price from Array_two
  },
  {
    "post_id": 16,
    "sku": "USBCV",
    "price": "99" //Updated Price from Array_two
  }
]
```

Comment: So and where do you have a problem? SO is about solving coding problems, not writing code for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with PHP. I did something similar with JS where I looped thru array_one and then uses `array_two.find()` to "connect" them together.

Answer (score 0):

First normalize array2 to `id=>price` using `array_column()`

```
$new_array2 = array_column($array2, 'price', 'id' );
```

That produces an array with `id` as key and `price` as value:

```
Array
(
    [DFTS-P20PR] => 49
    [SNTP-UVS8P] => 49
    [USBCV] => 99
    [KS-12SEA2] => 29
)
```

Now you can loop array1 and look up the new prices in new_array2 by testing for `$new_array2[ sku ]` and see if it exists.

```
$result=[];
foreach ($array1 as $value){
  if( isset( $new_array2[ $value['sku'] ] ) ){
     ... new price found
     $result[]=[
         'post_id'=> $value['post_id'],
         'sku'    => $value['sku'],
         'price'  => $new_array2[ $value['sku'] ]
         ];
     }
  else{
     ... use old price
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by creating my own find function.

```
// Match Products
$result = [];
    
function find($array, $key, $id) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($array as $product) {
        if ($product['id'] == $key) {
            $result['post_id'] = $id;
            $result['sku']     = $key;
            $result['price']   = $product['price'];
        } 
    }
    return $result;
}

foreach ($woProducts as $woProduct) {
    $matchedProduct = find($dbProducts, $woProduct['sku'], $woProduct['post_id']);
    array_push($result, $matchedProduct);
}

print_r($result);
```